# Mounting a virtual LDAP server on my machine (windows 2010)

Tags: java, web, ldap, jndi

I am working on a web application which uses an LDAP directory to manage authentication / authorization and I would like to test the functionalities linked to LDAP.

For that, I want to know if there is a possibility of mounting a virtual LDAP server on my machine (windows 2010) to be able to create a virtual directory and test it with the application.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, we can use Apache Directory Studio